# indexError:list index out of range

Tags: python

The program is for quick sort with duplicate keys.The code runs perfectly once or twice and then gives the IndexError next time eventhough the list is not empty.When I print the indices they lie within range.Is it a problem with my computer specifically?

EDIT-added the traceback

```
import random


def partition(n,lo,hi):
    i=lo
    lt=lo    #index showing the start of all duplicate partitioning keys
    gt=hi    #index showing the end of all duplicate partitioning keys
    x=n[lt]

    while(i<=gt):
        while(n[i]<=n[lt] and i<=gt):
            if(x!=n[lt]):
                print("alert!!!")
            if(n[i]<n[lt]): #current alement not a duplicate of partitioning alement
                if(lt<=i):
                    n[lt],n[i]=n[i],n[lt]
                    #print(n)
                i+=1
                lt+=1
            else: #current element is a duplicate partitioning alement
                #print(n[i],"=",n[lt])
                i+=1

        while(n[gt]>n[lt] and i<=gt):
            gt-=1

        if(i<gt):
            n[i],n[gt]=n[gt],n[i]
            gt-=1
            #print(n)


    return gt



def quickSort(n,lo,hi):
    #print("called")
    if(lo<hi):
        print(n)
        p=partition(n, lo, hi)
        quickSort(n, lo, p-1)
        quickSort(n, p+1, hi)

def main():
    nums=[]
    for i in range(30):
        nums.append(random.randrange(100))
    print("original array")
    print(nums)
    k=4
    hi=len(nums)-1
    #print(k,"th lowest number is ",quickSelect(nums, 0,hi,k))
    print(nums)
    quickSort(nums,0,hi)
    print(nums)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\S.reddy\workspace\sorter\src\selector\quickSelect.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()   
  File "C:\Users\S.reddy\workspace\sorter\src\selector\quickSelect.py", line 55, in main
    quickSort(nums,0,hi)
  File "C:\Users\S.reddy\workspace\sorter\src\selector\quickSelect.py", line 43, in quickSort
    quickSort(n, p+1, hi)
  File "C:\Users\S.reddy\workspace\sorter\src\selector\quickSelect.py", line 41, in quickSort
    p=partition(n, lo, hi)
  File "C:\Users\S.reddy\workspace\sorter\src\selector\quickSelect.py", line 11, in partition
    while(n[i]<=n[lt] and i<=gt):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: There cannot be a problem with the computer.

Comment: Please post the traceback too

Comment: Which values of `n, lo, hi` cause the problem?

Comment: @RoryDaulton i have no idea i printed all of them all seemed to be in range

Comment: I'd guess it's a short-circuiting issue (that is, you're not short-circuting properly, when you should be). Try reversing the order of the conditions you're testing with `and`: `while(i<=gt and n[i]<=n[lt])`. This way if `i` is greater than `gt` (and thus out of bounds), it will get noticed before the `n[i]` lookup is attempted.

Comment: @Blckknght that worked perfectly!! thanks.Write the answer if you want to and i will approve it :)

Comment: @Sidwa: I gave you the downvote because you did not show us the traceback or the parameter values that caused the error. You have since given the traceback but still have not given the parameter values.

Comment: @RoryDaulton if i knew which parameter values between i , lt , gt was the cause of the error. I probably wouldn't have had to ask the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was sometimes getting out of bounds indexes because of the order you were checking your conditions in your inner `while` loop.

Often an easy best way to debug issues like this is to add `try` and `except` blocks to the code, with the `except` block printing out useful diagnostic values. I used this variation on your loop to figure out the issue:

```
try:
    while(n[i]<=n[lt] and i<=gt):
        if(x!=n[lt]):
            print("alert!!!")
        if(n[i]<n[lt]): #current alement not a duplicate of partitioning alement
            if(lt<=i):
                n[lt],n[i]=n[i],n[lt]
                #print(n)
            i+=1
            lt+=1
        else: #current element is a duplicate partitioning alement
            #print(n[i],"=",n[lt])
            i+=1
except IndexError:
    print(i, gt, len(n))
    raise
```

You'll see that under certain circumstances, `gt` will be `len(n) - 1` and `i` will be `len(n)`. In that situation, the first test in `while(n[i]<=n[lt] and i<=gt):` will raise an `IndexError` since `n[i]` is not a valid index.

Instead, you should put the tests in the other order, with the `i <= gt` first. If that test is `False`, the `and` will "short-circuit" and not evaluate the second test, which is the one that would cause the exception. So: use `while i <= gt and n[i] <= n[lt]:` (The parentheses were unnecessary, so I've removed them and spaced out the terms from the operators. See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more recommendations on Python style.)

Comment: thanks for the try-except construct I didn't know it was there in python.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in row 11:

```
    while(n[i]<=n[lt] and i<=gt):
```

you need to change it to:

```
    while(i<=gt and n[i]<=n[lt]):
```

because python first checks first condition (in this case it is i<=gt) and if it is true than he checks the second one (n[i]<=n[lt]) but if the first condition is false then python exits while loop without checking second condition.